# momentJS UTC versus specifying the timezone in the moment constructor

Tags: momentjs, utc

Does the below 2 syntaxes are same,

1. `moment(1456261200367, 'H:mm:ss.SSS').utc().valueOf() //1456343786120`
2. `moment(1456261200367 +0000, 'H:mm:ss.SSS Z').valueOf() //1456325786120`

but as you could see if both of them coverts the given value to UTC mode then why there is a difference in the output?

Also I would like to know how `a.valueOf()` and `b.valueOf()` are same, when `a.format()` and `b.format()` are different, because `moment()` (moment parses and displays in local time) is different from `moment.utc()` (displays a moment in UTC mode)

```
var a = moment();
var b = moment.utc();
a.format();  
b.format();  
a.valueOf(); 
b.valueOf();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first part, you're using it incorrectly.  You've passed numeric input which would normally be interpreted as a unix timestamp, but then you've supplied a string-based format string so the number is converted to a string.  The format string here is telling moment how the **input** is specified, but it doesn't match what you're actually parsing.

This doesn't error though, because by default moment's parser is in "forgiving" mode.  You can read more about this [in the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

The correct way to pass a timestamp into moment is with one of these:

```
moment(1456261200367)
moment(1456261200367).utc()
moment.utc(1456261200367)
```

The last two are equivalent, but the `moment.utc(timestamp)` form is prefered.

With any of those, all three will have the same `.valueOf()`, which is just the timestamp you started with.  The difference is in the *mode* that the moment object is in.  The first one is in *local* mode, reflecting the time zone of the computer where it's running, while the other two are in UTC mode.

This is evident when you format the output using the `format` function, as with other many other functions.  I believe that answers your second question as well.

Comment: thank you for your reply. When i try to run moment(1456261200367) and moment.utc(1456261200367) as you mentioned i get the value i'm passing as the output i.e. 1456261200367, i was under the assumption that when i pass a non UTC timestamp value to moment(value).utc then i would expect a UTC compliant timestamp as output. Is that not the case (or) am i missing something here..